# SVG fill property

Tags: svg

i have `SVG` the `property(fill/stroke/stroke-width)` should be in `style="..."` or else out side

example :

`<rect x="10" y="10" fill="red" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" width="80px" height="50"/>`

-----------------------OR--------------------

`<rect x="10" y="10" style="fill:red; stroke:green; stroke-width:1;" width="80px" height="50"/>`

Which one is correct? Both are working and reason....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, both are correct. SVG was created in the late 90s. There all kinds of ideas how to auto-generate stuff were floating around. One was, for example, XSL-FO, which uses most of CSS's properties, but as attributes on elements:

```
<fo:block font-size="16px" color="red>Hello</fo:block>
```

In that time it seemed a good idea to double the possibilities to style SVG.

You need to take care, however, how the different properties cascade:

1. If an element has a `style` attribute, this is used first
2. If the SVG file has central CSS declarations, e.g., in a `<style>` element, those are used second.
3. The attribute is *only* used then, as fallback.

For illustration:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>rect { fill: yellow; }</style>

  <rect fill="red" style="fill: green" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

The resulting color of the `<rect>` is... green.